# ExpToTrig transforms solution to 4th order ODE into unwanted form

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic

*Mathematica* gives the solution of the second order differential equation

```
 DSolve[a y''[x] + b*y[x] == 0, y[x], x]
```

in trigonometric form

> ```
> {{y[x] -> C[1] Cos[(Sqrt[b] x)/Sqrt[a]] + C[2] Sin[(Sqrt[b] x)/Sqrt[a]]}}
> ```

In the fourth order case, *Mathematica* gives the solution in exponential form, which I tried to convert into trigonometric form

```
  ExpToTrig[DSolve[a y''''[x] + b*y[x] == 0, y[x], x]]
```

> ```
>  {{y[x] -> 
>       C[1] Cos[((1 + I) b^(1/4) x)/(Sqrt[2] a^(1/4))] + 
>       C[3] Cos[((1 + I) b^(1/4) x)/(Sqrt[2] a^(1/4))] + 
>       C[2] Cosh[((1 + I) b^(1/4) x)/(Sqrt[2] a^(1/4))] + 
>       C[4] Cosh[((1 + I) b^(1/4) x)/(Sqrt[2] a^(1/4))] + 
>       I C[1] Sin[((1 + I) b^(1/4) x)/(Sqrt[2] a^(1/4))] - 
>       I C[3] Sin[((1 + I) b^(1/4) x)/(Sqrt[2] a^(1/4))] - 
>       C[2] Sinh[((1 + I) b^(1/4) x)/(Sqrt[2] a^(1/4))] + 
>       C[4] Sinh[((1 + I) b^(1/4) x)/(Sqrt[2] a^(1/4))]}}
> ```

The problem is that I get a solution with hyperbolic functions, but I know that solution can be represented in purely trigonometric form. Another problem is that I get an imaginary part from multiplication of the constants `I C[1]` and `I C[3]`, which I wouldn't have a with trigonometric function solution. How can I transform the solution to a form having only trigonometric functions?

Comment: How about `HoldForm@Evaluate@DSolve[a y''''[x] + b*y[x] == 0, y[x], x] /. E^x_  :> (Cos[-I x] + I Sin[-I x])` ?